# Esper EPL Online Date format

Tags: esper

I'm trying to use the [Esper EPL Online console](http://esper-epl-tryout.appspot.com/epltryout/mainform.html) and I don't know how to use Dates in the Time And Event Sequence. For example, I have a schema defined like this:

```
create schema EventCreated(
  source String,
  type String,
  time Date
);
```

And I'm trying to add an event in the Time And Event Sequence, for example like this:

```
EventCreated = {
    source = 'tracker1',
    type = 'c8y_ObdConnectionReport',
    time =  '2016-10-07T10:00:00.000'
}
```

But of course this doesn't work. I tried using "new Date()" or [[com.espertech.esper.client.util.]DateTime.parseDefaultDate()](http://www.espertech.com/esper/release-5.2.0/esper-javadoc/com/espertech/esper/client/util/DateTime.html) but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an "eval" for evaluating EPL expressions.

```
StockTick={time=eval('com.espertech.esper.client.util.DateTime.parseDefaultDate("2016-10-07T10:00:00.000")')}
```

It would be nice though if the tool would just take the string and make it a date.